# findViewById(R.id.searchView) causing java null pointer exception

Tags: java, android

I have a really short question. I have an xml layout with a search button and a listview, and an activity for that.

XLM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <SearchView android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/locationList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private SearchView searchView;
    private ListView locationListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        locationListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.locationList );
    }
```

The line `searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);` simply gives the null pointer exception. I checked to change it to `EditText`, it works. Anyone idea why it is not working?

Thanks

Comment: This line where you find a `SearchView` can NOT give you a `NullPointerException` because you are not using a pointer there. It might give you a null `searchView` but not the exception. Please look at the stacktrace carefully.

Comment: Could you show the `SearchView` import in the activity? It can be imported from support library. If that's the case, so should your `XML`. Also, post the stack trace.

Comment: The error was basically `android.widget.SearchView` cannot be cast to `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`, so I just changed import `android.v7.widget.SearchView;` to import `android.widget.SearchView;`. But thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone who has commented on your question, the line where you're trying to find a searchview can't give you a NullPointerException, because you're not using a searchview that's null. `findViewById()` returns a view if it exists in the layout you provided in `setContentView()` i.e. activity_main, otherwise it returns null. I would suggest you to do two things:

- check if the layout that contain the searchview is named "activity_main"
- place a debug point on the next line from where you're finding the searchview
  and then run your debug tool, start your activity, check if you have a null searchview. If yes it might be something that have to do with your layout name. If not please search elsewhere in your
  code where you're getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: The error was basically `android.widget.SearchView` cannot be cast to `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`, so I just changed import `android.v7.widget.SearchView;` to import `android.widget.SearchView;`. But thanks for your support.